# How to Maintain the session for chromecast in android?

Tags: android, casting, chromecast

i have songs list where i just select that list and go to player page where i can cast the songs list on TV when connect the first time and i just sent those songs data in json object which has been passed to the receiver by using setCustomData method.

Code Part is :

```
if (mRemoteMediaPlayer == null || !mApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this.ctx, "No Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            return;
        }
        MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(
                MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC_TRACK);
        mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ALBUM_ARTIST, ""
                + singers.getText().toString());
        mediaMetadata.putString(mediaMetadata.KEY_ALBUM_TITLE, ""
                + songTitle.getText().toString());
        mediaMetadata
                .addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(cdImgurlList.get(0))));

MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(songUrl)
                .setContentType("audio/mp3")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setCustomData(customjsonArrayWrapper)  // here passing json object to the receiver
                .setMetadata(mediaMetadata).build();
        mRemoteMediaPlayer
                .load(mApiClient, mediaInfo, true)
                .setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResult(MediaChannelResult result) {
                                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Media loaded Successfully"
                                            + result.getStatus());
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            RaagaActivity.this,
                                            "Media Channel loaded Successfully"
                                                    + result.getStatus(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    // Update the UI While chrome casting
                                    UpdateUIControlsinCasting();

                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG,
                                            "Media loaded Not Successfully"
                                                    + result.getStatus());
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            RaagaActivity.this,
                                            "Media Channel not loaded Successfully"
                                                    + result.getStatus(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"IllegalStateException":e.getMessage();
        Log.e(TAG, err);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"Exception":e.getMessage();
        Log.e(TAG, err);
```

after successful casting those songs list and leave that page went to other app and returned to my app where i just selected another playlist and go to the player page again where cast button is disable mode and i need to reconnect the chromecast device, Session is not maintained. So Please help me to reconnect the same device which was previously connected device and Maintain the session when app in background state. I have referred from https://github.com/ivan-aguirre/chromecast_samples/blob/master/DropboxCast/app/src/main/java/com/dropboxcast/dropboxcast/CastController.java so tha i tried the Cast.CastApi.joinApplication(mApiClient, APP_ID, sessionID). but app is still crashing when come back to player page while playing with chromecast.How to solve this issues?

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain the session in your app across activities. Take a look at the Cast Companion Library which will do that for you: 
https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android

Comment: Thank you for response but u shared code is difficult to understand, Now app is working without crashing, but getting Exception as "No current media session", how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi Loen, Can u pls tell about mRemoteMediaPlayer.requestStatus(mApiClient).setResultCallback(), why we are using this Method?

Comment: The result callback will tell you if the API call was successful or not.

Comment: Thnaks, now i am getting Exception "No current media session" when accessing mRemoteMediaPlayer.seek(mApiClient, progress) in onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser). so how can i resolve this issues.? Pls help me

Comment: You need to have a media namespace channel with the receiver to control playback.

Comment: Ya, I have used CastApi.setMessageReceivedCallbacks(mApiClient,mRemoteMediaPlayer.getNamespace(),mRemoteMediaPlayer); but still am getting issue